# Words choice: Represent average per month for 6 months

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

I have been developing a question about averages. I gave 5 months' profit values and asked what should be the profit in the 6th month to get an average monthly profit of $X? My intention is to ask about the average profit per month for the period of six months.

Now my question is if the words *average monthly* correctly represent the intention. What if I use six-monthly average? Would it be better or would it change the sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*average monthly* is correct.

*six-monthly average* would change the sense to imply the average of six months, not each month.